# How to limit available virtual memory per process

Tags: linux, fedora, memory, limit

Occasionally some processes on my GNU/Linux desktop (such as gv and gnash) use up the physical memory and cause thrashing.  Since these processes aren't important, I want them to be automatically killed if they use too much memory.

I think the /etc/security/limits.conf file and the -v option could be used for this.  The question is whether it limits the amount of available memory per process of a particular user, or the sum for all the processes of a user.  Also I would like to ask how to make change to that file in effect without rebooting.

Comment: Related [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983120/limit-memory-usage-for-a-single-linux-process).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's also the `ulimit` mechanism. There's a system call (in Linux, it's a C library function) `ulimit(3)` and a Bash builtin `ulimit`. Type `ulimit -a` to see all the things you can limit to. To see the current virtual memory limit say `ulimit -v`. You can set it by saying `ulimit -v INTEGER-KILOBYTES`.

Running `ulimit` changes things for your *current* shell, and you can only select a value smaller than the current one. To run a command with limited virtual memory, you can just use a Bash sub-shell:

```
( ulimit -v 131072; some-app )
```

Comment: I found [this link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVJJU_6.4.0/com.ibm.IBMDS.doc_6.4/ds_ag_srv_adm_enforcing_min_ulimits.html) helpful. "Virtual memory size (`-v`): This option includes all types of memory that includes stack, heap, and memory-mapped files. Attempts to allocate memory in excess of this limit fails with an out-of-memory error. The value for this option is specified in kilobytes."

Comment: "Maximum resident set size (RSS) (`-m`): This option limits the amount of memory that can be swapped in to physical memory on behalf of any one process. The value for this option is specified in kilobytes." "Data segment (`-d`): This option limits the amount of memory that a process can allocate to a heap. The value for this option is specified in kilobytes." "Stack size (`-s`): This option limits the amount of memory a process can allocate to a stack. The value for this option is specified in kilobytes."

Comment: Personally I like doing e.g. `ulimit -v 1000000 && firefox` with `&&` instead of `;` [to make sure ulimit succeeds first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25669540/what-is-the-difference-between-double-ampersand-and-semicolon-in-linux)

Answer (score 4):

limits.conf will apply to users
example : 
oracle          soft    memlock        3145728
oracle          hard    memlock        3145728

otherwise if you re looking for a per process limit .. take a look at  sysctl -a 
for a permanent effect .. you could add your params to sysctl.conf

good luck