# Limit memory usage for a single Linux process

Tags: linux, memory, ulimit

I'm running `pdftoppm` to convert a user-provided PDF into a 300DPI image.  This works great, except if the user provides an PDF with a very large page size.  `pdftoppm` will allocate enough memory to hold a 300DPI image of that size in memory, which for a 100 inch square page is 100*300 * 100*300 * 4 bytes per pixel = 3.5GB.  A malicious user could just give me a silly-large PDF and cause all kinds of problems.

So what I'd like to do is put some kind of hard limit on memory usage for a child process I'm about to run--just have the process die if it tries to allocate more than, say, 500MB of memory.  Is that possible?

I don't think ulimit can be used for this, but is there a one-process equivalent?

Comment: Maybe `docker`?

Comment: See also: [Cannot enable cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1 on GCE Debian Jessie instance](https://serverfault.com/q/790318/113899)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28678/how-to-limit-available-virtual-memory-per-process

Comment: ulimit -v 1000000

Answer (score 78, accepted):

There's some problems with ulimit. Here's a useful read on the topic: [Limiting time and memory consumption of a program in Linux](http://coldattic.info/shvedsky/pro/blogs/a-foo-walks-into-a-bar/posts/40), which lead to the [timeout](https://github.com/pshved/timeout) tool, which lets you cage a process (and its forks) by time or memory consumption.

The timeout tool requires Perl 5+ and the `/proc` filesystem mounted. After that you copy the tool to e.g. `/usr/local/bin` like so:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pshved/timeout/master/timeout | \
  sudo tee /usr/local/bin/timeout && sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/timeout
```

After that, you can 'cage' your process by memory consumption as in your question like so:

```
timeout -m 500 pdftoppm Sample.pdf
```

Alternatively you could use `-t <seconds>` and `-x <hertz>` to respectively limit the process by time or CPU constraints.

The way this tool works is by checking multiple times per second if the spawned process has not oversubscribed its set boundaries. This means there actually is a small window where a process *could potentially* be oversubscribing before timeout notices and kills the process.

A more correct approach would hence likely involve cgroups, but that is much more involved to set up, even if you'd use Docker or runC, which among things, offer a more user-friendly abstraction around cgroups.

Comment: Seems to be working for me now (again?) but here's the google cache version: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:zfQQHbZqcZQJ:coldattic.info/shvedsky/pro/blogs/a-foo-walks-into-a-bar/posts/40+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Comment: Can we use timeout together with taskset (we need to limit both memory and cores) ?

Comment: It should be noted that this answer is not referring to the linux standard `coreutils` utility of the same name! Thus, the answer is potentially dangerous if anywhere on your system, some package has a script expecting `timeout` to be the linux standard `coreutils` package! I am unaware of this tool being packaged for distributions such as debian.

Comment: Does `-t <seconds>` constraint kill the process after that many seconds?

Comment: Might also be helpful that -m is accepting kilobytes. The example above suggests its using MB.

Answer (score 187):

Another way to limit this is to use Linux's control groups.  This is especially useful if you want to limit a process's (or group of processes') allocation of physical memory distinctly from virtual memory.  For example:

```
cgcreate -g memory:myGroup
echo 500M > /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/myGroup/memory.limit_in_bytes
echo 5G > /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/myGroup/memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes
```

will create a control group named `myGroup`, cap the set of processes run under `myGroup` up to 500 MB of physical memory with `memory.limit_in_bytes` and up to 5000 MB of physical and swap memory together with `memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes`.
More info about these options can be found here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/resource_management_guide/sec-memory

To run a process under the control group:

```
cgexec -g memory:myGroup pdftoppm
```

Note that on a modern Ubuntu distribution this example requires installing the [`cgroup-tools`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=cgroup-tools) package (previously [`cgroup-bin`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=cgroup-bin)):

```
sudo apt install cgroup-tools
```

and editing `/etc/default/grub` to change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1"
```

and then running `sudo update-grub` and rebooting to boot with the new kernel boot parameters.

Comment: The `firejail` program will also let you start a process with memory limits (using cgroups and namespaces to limit more than just memory). On my systems I did not have to change the kernel command line for this to work!

Comment: Do you need the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` modification to make the setting persistent? I found another way to make it persistent [here](http://www.fernandoalmeida.net/blog/how-to-limit-cpu-and-memory-usage-with-cgroups-on-debian-ubuntu/).

Comment: See also: [What does `swapaccount=1` in GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/531480/4784)

Comment: It would be useful to note in this answer that on some distributions (eg Ubuntu) sudo is required for cgcreate, and also the later commands unless permission is given to the current user. This would save the reader from having to find this information elsewhere (eg https://askubuntu.com/questions/345055). I suggested an edit to this effect but it was rejected.

Comment: `system-run` now appears to work perfectly on Ubuntu 22.04 without requiring modifying kernel params: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/536046/32558 I wonder how. But it does. That is the way to go now.

Comment: @Ferroao I updated that now.

Comment: `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory` is not being created for me on Ubuntu 22.04. I have set `cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1`.

Comment: In Ubuntu 22.04, the `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory` directory does not exist but creating a cgroup with `sudo cgcreate -g memory:myGroup` does create a directory named `/sys/fs/cgroup/myGroup`. However, this directory has no `memory.limit_in_bytes` file and is not writable, not even by the superuser. The files that it does contain appear to be _reporting_ statistics about resources used in the cgroup, but I don't see anything that controls them. I could `cgexec` a process in this cgroup (as superuser) and I see the peak memory use increase. Are these instructions RedHat-centric?

Answer (score 137):

On any systemd-based distro you can also use cgroups indirectly through [**systemd-run**](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-run.html). E.g. for your case of limiting `pdftoppm` to 500M of RAM, starting with cgroupsv2, you can simply do:

```
systemd-run --scope -p MemoryMax=500M --user pdftoppm
```

Previously, this [required booting with the `systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy` kernel parameter](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/13347#issuecomment-522477870), but tested as of Ubuntu 22.04 cgroup-tools                                  2.0-2, this does not seem to be the case anymore, the command just worked without any changes to the kernel parameters, and `systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy` is not set.

Before cgroupsv2 you could not use `--user`, and would instead run:

```bsh
systemd-run --scope -p MemoryMax=500M pdftoppm
```

but without `--user`, this will ask you for a password every time, even though the app gets launched as your user. Do not allow this to delude you into thinking that the command needs `sudo`, because that would cause the command to run under root, which was hardly your intention.

Comment: Short and sweet. Before I tried `firejail`, but that seemed to be overkill with too many side effects for *just* limiting memory consumption. Thanks!

Comment: Very good answer. Do you know is there a way not to kill the process after exceeding a limit but rather give a restriction to max memory usage ?

Comment: @EdiD I don't know a systemd option for that, but I presume disabling OOM-killer system-wide may make apps to receive `ENOMEM` instead of being killed. But in practice I can't think of much projects beside systems kernels that can gracefully handle OOM condition. Even those pure C projects that keep checking for malloc results, I don't they ever being tested in OOM conditions. So they'll misbehave, most likely crash. With that said, please check if you find [MemoryHigh](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html#MemoryHigh=bytes) more useful for your usecase

Comment: @Hi-Angel thanks I have just found this option too and testing now ...

Comment: Of note: If you use the `--user` option but don't have cgroupsv2 enabled (which is still the default in many distros), systemd-run will fail to set a memory limit but won't throw any errors. [Github issue](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/13347)

Comment: Sort of related -- do you know how to slow down I/O resource usage with it?

Comment: @Volomike there's a number of IO-related hooks. `IOWeight` might be something you're interested in. Please see [the documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html)

Comment: @CiroSantilli are you sure the command really worked for you? Unfortunately `--user` is just ignored when the kernel parameter is not set, so this may have silently failed on you and you just didn't notice. You can check if it works by limiting an application to ridiculously low amount of memory, e.g. 1K, and seeing if it fail to launch *(which it should)*.

Comment: I've just retested, and it does seem to work, a C hello world gets killed with `systemd-run --scope -p MemoryMax=1 --user ./hello.out` or `1K`, but runs fine with `systemd-run --scope -p MemoryMax=1M --user ./hello.out`.  And `sudo dmesg | less` shows CLI: `Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/BOOT/ubuntu_uvs1fq@/vmlinuz-5.15.0-27-generic root=ZFS=rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_uvs1fq ro`. I did get the notification here as well BTW :-)

Comment: In the end, this was the type of solution that worked for me (the cgroup instructions don't seem to apply to Ubuntu: system files are named differently). HOWEVER, it was necessary to set both `-p MemoryMax=10M` and `-p MemorySwapMax=10M`. Otherwise, the running process could still `malloc` large blocks of memory; they were just slower to access (because they were physically on disk).

Comment: @JimPivarski this is weird, I think it's unexpected. Docs claim `MemoryMax` to be "the absolute limit on memory usage". Also, I can't reproduce your behavior: I have a SWAP partition, but running a `systemd-run --scope -p MemoryMax=1K --user ls` results in `ls` being killed as opposed to `ls` being ran slow. Adding a `-p MemorySwapMax=1G` changes nothing, it's still killed as expected. I currently have systemd 252. I think you need to report a bug.

Comment: Tried it on browsers, firefox and chrome. Works perfect. Both browsers spawn several processes, but in the end, they are limited to the memory assigned in the command. I assigned 500 for firefox and 2GB for chrome. I don't feel any performance issue.

Answer (score 101):

If your process doesn't spawn more children that consume the most memory, you may use [`setrlimit`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) function.  More common user interface for that is using `ulimit` command of the shell:

```
$ ulimit -Sv 500000     # Set ~500 mb limit
$ pdftoppm ...
```

This will only limit "virtual" memory of your process, taking into account—and limiting—the memory the process being invoked shares with other processes, and the memory mapped but not reserved (for instance, Java's large heap).  Still, virtual memory is the closest approximation for processes that grow really large, making the said errors insignificant.

If your program spawns children, and it's them which allocate memory, it becomes more complex, and you should write auxiliary scripts to run processes under your control. I wrote in my blog, [why](http://coldattic.info/shvedsky/pro/blogs/a-foo-walks-into-a-bar/posts/40) and [how](http://coldattic.info/shvedsky/pro/resourcelimit).

Comment: why is `setrlimit` more complex for more children? `man setrlimit` tells me that "A child process created via fork(2) inherits its parents resource limits. Resource limits are preserved across execve(2)"

Comment: Because the kernel does not sum the vm size for all child processes; if it did it would get the answer wrong anyway. The limit is per-process, and is virtual address space, not memory usage. Memory usage is harder to measure.

Comment: if i understand the question correctly then OP whats the limit per subprocess (child) .. not in total.

Comment: @MarkR, anyway, virtual address space is a good approximation for the memory used, especially if you run a program that's not controlled by a virtual machine (say, Java).  At least I don't know any better metric.

Comment: Virtual address space is the best we really have; there isn't an easily measurable alternative. The pages measured don't need to be in core, they don't need to be private to that process, they're still counted.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks - this `ulimit` approach helped me with `firefox`'s [bug 622816 – Loading a large image can "freeze" firefox, or crash the system](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=622816); which on a USB boot (from RAM) tends to freeze the OS, requiring hard restart; now at least `firefox` crashes itself, leaving the OS alive... Cheers!

Comment: What are the soft and hard limits?

Comment: do you just run the command after this?

Comment: On 32 bits machines, the maximum limit is 2 GiB (or unlimited), cf `RLIMIT_AS` in [man (2) setrlimit](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit).

Comment: I want to use this approach for chrome. As far I understand, only child process will fail that is 16G, not the whole chrome?

Comment: The ulimit on my system doesn't have any -S option.  I wonder what that was for?
The -v500000 parameter is said to specify 500 mbytes.  My "man" page for ulimit doesn't specify any units for the -v parameter.  I'm guessing -s takes a kbytes param.  In that case, in the answer here, I'm guessing it was supposed to be -v512000 to specify 500 mbytes.

Comment: @wsdzbm

> What are the soft and hard limits?

hard limit for all users in the system, set by the administrator.
soft limit, which each user can set themselves

Comment: why set "virtual memory" (`-v`) and not "max memory size"  (`-m`)

Answer (score 17):

As of 2022 / Ubuntu 22.04 the below script is obsolete. Ubuntu 22.04 no longer mounts cgroups v1 by default, and systemd-run now supports everything needed. The command to run a program with a hard memory limit is

```
systemd-run --user --scope -p MemoryMax=<memorylimit> \
  -p MemorySwapMax=<swaplimit> <command>
```

- Note that memory and swap have separate limits, unlike the `memory.memsw.*` control files in cgroups v1 which controlled the total amount of memory + swap used. I have so far not found a way to set a limit on the combined memory + swap.
- There is also a `MemoryHigh` parameter which is less strict than `MemoryMax`. It won't kill the processes but starts to throttle them and agressively swap out memory.

The below script can be adapted to run on cgroups v2 as per [Ciro Santilli's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/701247/50793), but with `systemd-run` now doing everything necessary there is no need to. I have a script similar to that from my original answer that works with `systemd-run` posted in a [new answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/768844/50793).

---

*Original answer:*

I'm using the below script, which works great. <strike>It uses cgroups through `cgmanager`.</strike> *Update: it now uses the commands from `cgroup-tools`.* Name this script `limitmem` and put it in your $PATH and you can use it like `limitmem 100M bash`. This will limit both memory and swap usage. To limit just memory remove the line with `memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes`.

*edit:* On default Linux installations this only limits memory usage, not swap usage. To enable swap usage limiting, you need to enable swap accounting on your Linux system. Do that by setting/adding `swapaccount=1` in `/etc/default/grub` so it looks something like

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="swapaccount=1"
```

Then run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

Disclaimer: I wouldn't be surprised if `cgroup-tools` also breaks in the future. The correct solution would be to use the systemd api's for cgroup management but there are no command line tools for that a.t.m.

*edit (2021)*: Until now this script still works, but it goes against Linux's recommendation to have a single program manage your cgroups. Nowadays that program is usually systemd. Unfortunately systemd has a number of limitations that make it difficult to replace this script with systemd invocations. The `systemd-run --user` command should allow a user to run a program with resource limitations, but that isn't supported on cgroups v1. (Everyone uses cgroups v1 because docker doesn't work on cgroupsv2 yet except for the very latest versions.) With root access (which this script also requires) it should be possible to use `systemd-run` to create the correct systemd-supported cgroups, and then manually set the memory and swap properties in the right cgroup, but that is still to be implemented. See also [this bug comment](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/10581#issuecomment-434643635) for context, and [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/resource_management_guide/sec-modifying_control_groups#ex-Configuring_Cgroup_Options) and [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html#MemorySwapMax=bytesq) for relevant documentation.

According to @Mikko's comment using a script like this with systemd runs the risk of systemd losing track of processes in a sessions. I haven't noticed such problems, but I use this script mostly on a single-user machine.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

# This script uses commands from the cgroup-tools package. The cgroup-tools commands access the cgroup filesystem directly which is against the (new-ish) kernel's requirement that cgroups are managed by a single entity (which usually will be systemd). Additionally there is a v2 cgroup api in development which will probably replace the existing api at some point. So expect this script to break in the future. The correct way forward would be to use systemd's apis to create the cgroups, but afaik systemd currently (feb 2018) only exposes dbus apis for which there are no command line tools yet, and I didn't feel like writing those.

# strict mode: error if commands fail or if unset variables are used
set -eu

if [ "$#" -lt 2 ]
then
    echo Usage: `basename $0` "<limit> <command>..."
    echo or: `basename $0` "<memlimit> -s <swaplimit> <command>..."
    exit 1
fi

cgname="limitmem_$$"

# parse command line args and find limits

limit="$1"
swaplimit="$limit"
shift

if [ "$1" = "-s" ]
then
    shift
    swaplimit="$1"
    shift
fi

if [ "$1" = -- ]
then
    shift
fi

if [ "$limit" = "$swaplimit" ]
then
    memsw=0
    echo "limiting memory to $limit (cgroup $cgname) for command $@" >&2
else
    memsw=1
    echo "limiting memory to $limit and total virtual memory to $swaplimit (cgroup $cgname) for command $@" >&2
fi

# create cgroup
sudo cgcreate -g "memory:$cgname"
sudo cgset -r memory.limit_in_bytes="$limit" "$cgname"
bytes_limit=`cgget -g "memory:$cgname" | grep memory.limit_in_bytes | cut -d\  -f2`

# try also limiting swap usage, but this fails if the system has no swap
if sudo cgset -r memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes="$swaplimit" "$cgname"
then
    bytes_swap_limit=`cgget -g "memory:$cgname" | grep memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes | cut -d\  -f2`
else
    echo "failed to limit swap"
    memsw=0
fi

# create a waiting sudo'd process that will delete the cgroup once we're done. This prevents the user needing to enter their password to sudo again after the main command exists, which may take longer than sudo's timeout.
tmpdir=${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR:-$TMPDIR}
tmpdir=${tmpdir:-/tmp}
fifo="$tmpdir/limitmem_$$_cgroup_closer"
mkfifo --mode=u=rw,go= "$fifo"
sudo -b sh -c "head -c1 '$fifo' >/dev/null ; cgdelete -g 'memory:$cgname'"

# spawn subshell to run in the cgroup. If the command fails we still want to remove the cgroup so unset '-e'.
set +e
(
set -e
# move subshell into cgroup
sudo cgclassify -g "memory:$cgname" --sticky `sh -c 'echo $PPID'`  # $$ returns the main shell's pid, not this subshell's.
exec "$@"
)

# grab exit code 
exitcode=$?

set -e

# show memory usage summary

peak_mem=`cgget -g "memory:$cgname" | grep memory.max_usage_in_bytes | cut -d\  -f2`
failcount=`cgget -g "memory:$cgname" | grep memory.failcnt | cut -d\  -f2`
percent=`expr "$peak_mem" / \( "$bytes_limit" / 100 \)`

echo "peak memory used: $peak_mem ($percent%); exceeded limit $failcount times" >&2

if [ "$memsw" = 1 ]
then
    peak_swap=`cgget -g "memory:$cgname" | grep memory.memsw.max_usage_in_bytes | cut -d\  -f2`
    swap_failcount=`cgget -g "memory:$cgname" |grep memory.memsw.failcnt | cut -d\  -f2`
    swap_percent=`expr "$peak_swap" / \( "$bytes_swap_limit" / 100 \)`

    echo "peak virtual memory used: $peak_swap ($swap_percent%); exceeded limit $swap_failcount times" >&2
fi

# remove cgroup by sending a byte through the pipe
echo 1 > "$fifo"
rm "$fifo"

exit $exitcode
```

Comment: `call to cgmanager_create_sync failed: invalid request` for every process I try to run with `limitmem 100M processname`. I'm on Xubuntu 16.04 LTS and that package is installed.

Comment: Ups, I get this error message:
`$ limitmem 400M rstudio
    limiting memory to 400M (cgroup limitmem_24575) for command rstudio
    Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: invalid request`

any idea?

Comment: @RKiselev cgmanager is deprecated now, and not even available in Ubuntu 17.10. The systemd api that it uses was changed at some point, so that's probably the reason. I have updated the script to use cgroup-tools commands.

Comment: if the calculation for `percent` results in zero, the `expr` status code is 1, and this script exits prematurely. recommend changing the line to: `percent=$(( "$peak_mem" / $(( "$bytes_limit" / 100 )) ))` (ref: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63166/bash-e-exits-when-let-or-expr-evaluates-to-0)

Comment: how can I config cgroup to kill my process if I go above the limit?

Comment: @d9ngle You don't really need to, Linux won't allow the process to go above the limit. Memory allocations will fail or the OOM killer will kill the process. Otherwise there's the `memory.failcnt` and `memory.memsw.failcnt` files in the cgroup directory that you could monitor to see if the count gets above 0, but that may not be what you want as when that first happens there is usually memory in your process somewhere that the OS can reclaim without harm (e.g. mapped files).

Comment: @JanKanis I forgot to tag you. Please see my answer below.

Comment: Poettering has an opinion that if your system is running `systemd` no other apps should be messing with `cgroup`s. As a result, you should be using `systemd-run --user --pty -p ... ...` but unless your system is already running `cgroupv2` all memory limits will fail silently and no limitations apply. For example, you need Ubuntu 21.10 or greater in practice.

Comment: @mikko you're right, see also the first comment line of the script. When I wrote the scripts originally the right tools didn't exist yet. It still works for me but maybe it's time to figure out how systemd-run works.

Comment: It's my understanding that `systemd` session handling *may* fail if you run anything that touches the `cgroup` hierarchies. For most cases you should be fine on single user desktop system. And in my experience, at least Ubuntu 18.04 has many other bugs that cause some processes to leak out of session handling so it's not perfect in any case.

Comment: @mikko I have never noticed any session handling problems, but I run this on a single user desktop. For my use case the risk is an acceptable price for my whole system not crashing due to OOM.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the tools from `daemontools`, suggested by Mark Johnson, you can also consider `chpst` which is found in `runit`. Runit itself is bundled in `busybox`, so you might already have it installed.

The [man page of `chpst`](http://smarden.org/runit/chpst.8.html) shows the option:

> -m bytes
>       limit memory. Limit the data segment, stack segment, locked physical pages, and total of all segment per process to bytes bytes
>   each.

Answer (score 5):

**cgroupsv2 update (Ubuntu 22.04)**

Things have moved around a bit. Compared to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125024/32558 now you now need:

```
sudo cgcreate -a $USER:$USER -g memory:myGroup -t $USER:$USER
sudo cgset -r memory.max=500M myGroup
sudo cgset -r memory.swap.max=0 myGroup
sudo chmod o+w /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.procs
cgexec -g memory:myGroup mycmd arg0 arg1
```

The line:

```
sudo chmod o+w /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.procs
```

is needed for it to work without `sudo`: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406329/how-to-run-cgexec-without-sudo-as-current-user-on-ubuntu-22-04-with-cgroups-v2/1450845#1450845 otherwise it fails with:

```
cgroup change of group failed
```

If you don't run that command, you can also use:

```
sudo cgexec -g memory:myGroup mycmd arg0 arg1
```

but then that runs as `root`, which you usually don't want it to do, this can be tested with `sudo cgexec -g memory:myGroup id`.

Compared to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125024/32558 which was originally for v1:

- `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/myGroup/memory.limit_in_bytes` is now `/sys/fs/cgroup/myGroup/memory.max`
- `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/myGroup/memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes` was split, now you just set the swap separatelly in `/sys/fs/cgroup/myGroup/memory.swap.max` rather than the sum

For the specific case of memory however, just use `systemd-run` as mentioned at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/536046/32558 that just worked and is by far the simplest approach.

**Testing it out**

malloc_touch.c

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    size_t nbytes, step;
    if (argc > 1) {
        nbytes = strtoull(argv[1], NULL, 0);
    } else {
        nbytes = 0x10;
    }
    if (argc > 2) {
        step = strtoull(argv[2], NULL, 0);
    } else {
        step = 1;
    }

    char *base = malloc(nbytes);
    assert(base);
    char *i = base;
    while (i < base + nbytes) {
        *i = 13;
        i += step;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/0195cc01dfac7a720332250b4d7352add39f19b0/userland/c/malloc_touch.c).

First we find that `1M` is about the minimum at which a C hello world will run:

```
sudo cgset -r memory.max=1M myGroup
cgexec -g memory:myGroup ./malloc_touch.out
```

Then starting from there we can try to malloc 100k:

```
sudo cgset -r memory.max=1M myGroup
cgexec -g memory:myGroup ./malloc_touch.out 100000
```

OK, there was still some left. Then if try 1M:

```
sudo cgset -r memory.max=1M myGroup
cgexec -g memory:myGroup ./malloc_touch.out 1000000
```

Killed as expected. Increase limit to 10M:

```
sudo cgset -r memory.max=10M myGroup
cgexec -g memory:myGroup ./malloc_touch.out 1000000
```

OK. Malloc 9M:

```
sudo cgset -r memory.max=10M myGroup
cgexec -g memory:myGroup ./malloc_touch.out 9000000
```

OK. Malloc 10M:

```
sudo cgset -r memory.max=10M myGroup
cgexec -g memory:myGroup ./malloc_touch.out 10000000
```

OK. Humm, not sure why, expected it to die. MiB vs MB? Try 11M

```
sudo cgset -r memory.max=10M myGroup
cgexec -g memory:myGroup ./malloc_touch.out 11000000
```

Killed as expected.

Tested on Ubuntu 22.10.

**cgcreate is completely broken on Ubuntu 21.10**

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1376093/is-cgroup-tools-using-cgroup-v1-or-v2

Fails with:

```
cgcreate: libcgroup initialization failed: Cgroup is not mounted
```

Apparently they moved part of the system to v2 but not the other.

Answer (score 4):

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and JanKanis script doesn't work for me quite as he suggests. Running `limitmem 100M script` is limiting 100MB of RAM with **unlimited** swap.

Running `limitmem 100M -s 100M script` fails silently as `cgget -g "memory:$cgname"` has no parameter named `memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes`.

So I disabled swap:

```
# create cgroup
sudo cgcreate -g "memory:$cgname"
sudo cgset -r memory.limit_in_bytes="$limit" "$cgname"
sudo cgset -r memory.swappiness=0 "$cgname"
bytes_limit=`cgget -g "memory:$cgname" | grep memory.limit_in_bytes | cut -d\  -f2`
```

Comment: @sourcejedi added it :)

Comment: Right, I edited my answer. To enable swap limits you need to enable swap accounting on your system. There's a small runtime overhead to that so it isn't enabled by default on Ubuntu. See my edit.

Answer (score 4):

While this isn't what the OP originally asked for, but for the sake of completeness, for processes that are already running, I use [prlimit](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/prlimit.1.html)

E.G. `$ prlimit -v1073741824 -pid <xx>`

Sets the max limit for memory to 1 Gibibyte. One can set both soft limits (and carry out custom actions such as email) and hard limits.

Comment: [prlimit(1) has never been limited to already running commands](https://karelzak.blogspot.com/2012/01/prlimit1.html)! You can do e.g. `prlimit -v1073741824 pdftoppm`.

Comment: @Devon Thanks for completing the completeness attempt :D , I'd focussed on just what some of the other options mentioned here can't do.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer to the question as posed, but:

Could you check the file-size, to prevent issues BEFORE trying to process a pdf? That would remove the "ridiculously large" issue.

There are also programs that will process a pdf (there are python programs, for instance: http://theautomatic.net/2020/01/21/how-to-read-pdf-files-with-python/) whereby one could split the pdf into more manageable-sized chunks. Or do both: if the file-size is reasonable, process it; otherwise (else) split it into as many pieces as required, and process those. One could then re-combine the outputs. One might need to have some overlap between sections to prevent "border" issues.

Limiting the available memory might well force a failure to process larger files, or lead to massive memory swap issues.

Answer (score 1):

I also like to limit the memory of some of my programs, so I have an updated script from my [previous answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/279175/50793) that works with systemd as the cgroup manager. In order not to clutter the other answer, I'll add it here as a new answer.

Usage: `limitmem 500M -s 200M <program>`

That will hard-limit the program to 500M of ram and 200M swap, for a total of 700M memory usage. If swap usage is not specified, the below script will default to a limit of 1 GB. The new cgroups (v2) system unfortunately does not offer an integrated total virtual memory use control that would allow the kernel to partition between ram and swap use.

If the program is a Snap package (which starts its own cgroup, thereby leaving the cgroup limitmem puts it in), add the `--snap` flag.

The script (save as ~/bin/limitmem)

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

# strict mode: error if commands fail or if unset variables are used
set -eu

limit=''
swaplimit="1G"
snap=0

while true
do
    # parse command line args and find limits

    if [ "$#" -lt 1 -o "$1" = "-h" -o "$1" = "--help" ]
    then
            echo Usage: `basename "$0"` "[--snap] <limit> <command>..."
            echo or: `basename "$0"` "[--snap] <memlimit> -s <swaplimit> <command>..."
            echo
            echo Pass "--snap" if the command is a Snap app, which will place itself into a systemd scope
            exit 1
    fi

    if [ "$1" = "-s" ]
    then
            shift
            swaplimit="$1"
            shift
            continue
    fi

    if [ "$1" = "--snap" ]
    then
        shift
        snap=1
        continue
    fi

    if [ "$1" = -- ]
    then
        shift
            break
    fi

    if [ "$limit" = "" ]
    then
        limit="$1"
        shift
        continue
    fi

    break  # Reached start of command
done

if [ "$snap" = 0 ]
then
    exec systemd-run --user --scope -p MemoryMax="$limit" -p MemorySwapMax="$swaplimit" "$@"
else
    scopename=snap.`basename "$1"`.\*
    (
        sleep 2;
        systemctl set-property --user "$scopename" MemoryMax="$limit" MemorySwapMax="$swaplimit"
    )&
    exec "$@"
fi
```

I use a customized version of the above that records the processes and their cgroups, so another fish shell function I have can show a nice overview of the memory usage. This version depends on fish shell and being uid 1000:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

# strict mode: error if commands fail or if unset variables are used
set -eu

limit=''
swaplimit="1G"
snap=0

while true
do
    # parse command line args and find limits

    if [ "$#" -lt 1 -o "$1" = "-h" -o "$1" = "--help" ]
    then
            echo Usage: `basename "$0"` "[--snap] <limit> <command>..."
            echo or: `basename "$0"` "[--snap] <memlimit> -s <swaplimit> <command>..."
            echo
            echo Pass "--snap" if the command is a Snap app, which will place itself into a systemd scope
            exit 1
    fi

    if [ "$1" = "-s" ]
    then
            shift
            swaplimit="$1"
            shift
            continue
    fi

    if [ "$1" = "--snap" ]
    then
        shift
        snap=1
        continue
    fi

    if [ "$1" = -- ]
    then
        shift
            break
    fi

    if [ "$limit" = "" ]
    then
        limit="$1"
        shift
        continue
    fi

    break  # Reached start of command
done

if [ "$snap" = 0 ]
then
    exec systemd-run --user --scope -p MemoryMax="$limit" -p MemorySwapMax="$swaplimit" fish -c "set -U JCLIMITMEM \$JCLIMITMEM (basename \"$1\"):(string split -f3 -m2 : (grep 0:: /proc/self/cgroup)); exec \$argv" -- "$@"
else
    scopename=snap.`basename "$1"`.\*
    fish -c "set -U JCLIMITMEM \$JCLIMITMEM (basename \"$1\"):\"/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/$scopename\"; echo \$JCLIMITMEM"
    (
        sleep 2;
        systemctl set-property --user "$scopename" MemoryMax="$limit" MemorySwapMax="$swaplimit"
    )&
    exec "$@"
fi
```

With this fish function to show current memory usage:

```fish
function memoryusage
    set -l valid_cgroups
    for g in $JCLIMITMEM
        set -l name (string split -f1 : $g)
        set -l cgroup (string split -f2 -m1 : $g)

        if ! [ -d (fish -c "echo /sys/fs/cgroup/$cgroup" 2>/dev/null) ]
            continue
        end
        if ! contains $name:$cgroup $valid_cgroups
            set valid_cgroups $valid_cgroups $name:$cgroup
        end

        set -l c (fish -c "echo /sys/fs/cgroup/$cgroup" 2>/dev/null)

        set -l limit (cat $c/memory.max)
        #set -l max (cat "$c/memory.peak")
        set -l curr (cat "$c/memory.current")
        set -l failcnt (string split -f2 \  (grep oom\  "$c/memory.events"))

        #set -l maxp (math "floor ($max * 100 / $limit)")
        set -l currp (math "floor ($curr * 100 / $limit)")
        set -l GB 1073741824
        set -l limitgb (math "floor ($limit / $GB)")
        set -l limitgbfrac (math "floor (($limit - $limitgb*$GB) * 100 / $GB)")
        #set -l maxgb (math "floor ($max / $GB)")
        #set -l maxgbfrac (math "floor (($max - $maxgb*$GB) * 100 / $GB)")
        set -l currgb (math "floor ($curr / $GB)")
        set -l currgbfrac (math "floor (($curr - $currgb*$GB) * 100 / $GB)")

        echo $name:
        printf "limit:     %12d %9s.%02d GB)\n" $limit "($limitgb" $limitgbfrac
        #printf "max usage: %12d %5s, %2d.%02d GB)\n" $max "($maxp%" $maxgb $maxgbfrac
        printf "usage:     %12d %5s, %2d.%02d GB)\n" $curr "($currp%" $currgb $currgbfrac
        printf "failcount: %12d\n" $failcnt
        echo
    end
    set JCLIMITMEM $valid_cgroups
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**Ubuntu 22.04** 
To resolve it you need to boot your host system into CGroupV1 mode by modifying your kernel’s boot arguments to include:
`systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=false`.

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

(or other editor of your choice). 
Add/change

> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1 systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=false"
> ```

in the file.

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

Comment: (1) You seem to be contradicting [Hi-Angel’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/44985/80216#536046). If so, you should say so. (2) This doesn’t seem to be an actual answer, but just commentary on one or more of the existing answer(s).

Comment: Also, please don’t post [nearly-identical answers](https://askubuntu.com/q/1406329/325633#1414753 "How to run cgexec without sudo as current user on Ubuntu 22.04 with cgroups v2, failing with "cgroup change of group failed"?   (on Ask Ubuntu)") to multiple questions within Stack Exchange without linking between them.