# Does 'ulimit -m' not work on (modern) Linux?

Tags: linux, memory, ulimit, resources

[This article](http://thirld.com/blog/2012/02/09/things-to-remember-when-using-ulimit/) claims that the `-m` flag to `ulimit` does nothing in modern Linux.  I can find nothing else to corroborate this claim.  Is it accurate?

> You may try to limit the memory usage of a process by setting the maximum resident set size (ulimit -m). This has no effect on Linux. man setrlimit says it used to work only in ancient versions. You should limit the maximum amount of virtual memory (ulimit -v) instead.

If it's true that it worked in older versions of Linux, which version stopped supporting this?

Comment: Here's an interesting article which goes into some detail about the various limits and what they mean.  It's ten years old but presumably most of this stuff doesn't change.  http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/311442.html

Comment: Related: [Limit memory usage for a single Linux process](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/44985/1174)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It says right there in the article:

> This has no effect on Linux. man setrlimit says it used to work only
> in ancient versions.

The [setrlimit](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) man page says:

> ```
>  RLIMIT_RSS
>         Specifies the limit (in pages) of the process's resident set
>         (the number of virtual pages resident in RAM).  This limit has
>         effect only in Linux 2.4.x, x < 30, and there affects only
>         calls to madvise(2) specifying MADV_WILLNEED.
> ```

So it stopped working in **2.4.30**.
The [changelog for 2.4.30](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.4/ChangeLog-2.4.30) says something about this:

> Marcelo Tosatti:
> o Ake Sandgren: Fix RLIMIT_RSS madvise calculation bug
> o Hugh Dickins: remove rlim_rss and this RLIMIT_RSS code from madvise. Presumably the code crept in by mistake

Comment: Thanks. I looked through the setrlimit page, but didn't know what to look for.

Comment: You had to look for `resident` from *resident set size*.