# Cannot set memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes in cgroup on Ubuntu server using cgm

Tags: cgroups

I'm trying to limit resource usage for a cgroup without having root access.

I can set memory.limit_in_bytes using cgm setvalue memory  memory.limit_in_bytes 150G

But I can not set memsw.limit_in_bytes in the same way, regardless of whether memsw.limit_in_bytes is greater than memory.limit_in_bytes (This is necessary, because the memsw option sets maximum memory + swap limit)

All I receive is: Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: invalid request

Any ideas?

Comment: Possibly related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125024

Answer (score 0):

When using `cgm`, beware that `cgm chown $controller $cgroup $uid $gid` only changes the owner of the `/sys/fs/cgroup/$controller/$cgroup` directory and its `cgroup.procs` and `tasks` files. Unprivileged users who cannot write to those files will get an *call to cgmanager_set_value_sync failed: invalid request* message as you found out.

Another possibility is that the file is missing, for example due to missing swap support in the kernel. If your kernel is not configured with `CONFIG_MEMCG_SWAP_ENABLED`, then you have to pass the `swapaccount=1` cmdline option.