# Is setting ulimit -v sufficient to avoid memory leak

Tags: linux, rhel, ulimit

We have a process that in recent weeks had a once-off memory leak that resulted in it consuming all memory on our RHEL 7 box

We now wish to set limits around this such that it will never take any more than a certain amount

We are using the ulimit -v setting to set this amount (as the -m setting does not work)

Therefore, I'm wondering if this is sufficient or do we also need a way to limit physical memory as well? IF so, what is the best way to go about this?

If virtual memory always grows with phyiscal memory then perhaps -v by itself is sufficient

Comment: How to use cgroups, the current solution since `ulimit -m` does not work: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44985/limit-memory-usage-for-a-single-linux-process

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some description about how `ulimit` works:

`ulimit` has deal with [`setrlimit`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) and [`getrlimit`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/getrlimit) system calls. It's easy to ensure by `strace`-ing of bash process (`ulimit` is component of the `bash`). I set 1024kb of `max memory size`:

```
$ ulimit -m 1024
```

In another console:

```
$ strace -p <my_bash_pid>
. . .
getrlimit(RLIMIT_RSS, {rlim_cur=1024*1024, rlim_max=1024*1024}) = 0
setrlimit(RLIMIT_RSS, {rlim_cur=1024*1024, rlim_max=1024*1024}) = 0
. . .
```

`setrlimit` man page write next about `RLIMIT_RSS`:

> **RLIMIT_RSS** Specifies the limit (in pages) of the process's resident
>   set (the number of virtual pages resident in RAM). This limit only has
>   effect in **Linux 2.4.x, x < 30**, and there only affects calls to
>   **madvise(2)** specifying MADV_WILLNEED.

[`madvice`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/madvise) syscall is just advice to kernel and kernel may ignore this advice. Even `bash` man page about `ulimit` write following:

> -m     The maximum resident set size **(many systems do not honor this limit)**

That is the reason why `-m` doesn't work.

About `-v` option:

I set 1024 kb of virtual memory:

```
$ ulimit -v 1024
```

In another console:

```
$ strace -p <my_bash_pid>
. . .
getrlimit(RLIMIT_AS, {rlim_cur=RLIM64_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
setrlimit(RLIMIT_AS, {rlim_cur=1024*1024, rlim_max=1024*1024}) = 0
. . .
```

`setrlimit` man page write next about `RLIMIT_AS`:

> **RLIMIT_AS** The maximum size of the process's virtual memory (address
>   space) in bytes. This limit affects calls to **brk(2)**, **mmap(2)** and
>   **mremap(2)**, which fail with the error ENOMEM upon exceeding this limit.
>   Also automatic stack expansion will fail (and generate a SIGSEGV that
>   kills the process if no alternate stack has been made available via
>   sigaltstack(2)). Since the value is a long, on machines with a 32-bit
>   long either this limit is at most 2 GiB, or this resource is
>   unlimited.

Program consist of 3 segments (data, code, stack) compose virtual program memory space.

- Code segment is const and contain program instructions.
- Data segment is controlled by following:

  [`brk`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/brk) syscall adjusts size of *data segment* (part of virtual memory) of the program.

  [`mmap`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) syscall maps file or device to virtual memory of process.

  Many programs allocates memory (direct or indirect) by calling standard function from C Library (`malloc`) which allocates memory from *heap* (part of data segment). `malloc` adjust size of data segment by calling `brk` syscall.
- Stack stores functions variables (variable takes memory during allocation from stack).

So, that's why the `-v` option is works for you.

If `-v` is sufficient for your task, then there is no reasons to do something else and it's sufficient.

---

If you want to take control about huge count of specific memory features for process (memory pressure, swap usage, RSS limit, OOM and so on) I suggest to you to use [*cgroups memory*](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/memory.txt) capabilities.

If your application is a *service* I suggest to you to use [*systemd slice*](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.slice.html) features, as the most convenient for controlling and limiting resources of service or group of services (also it easy to configure instead of configuring `cgroups` directly) which is managed by `systemd`.