# memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes: Invalid argument

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, cgroups

I have a Debian 10 server and I am trying to limit the memory + swap of a user using cgroups2.

Using `memory.limit_in_bytes` works fine, but I want to limit the memory+swap using `memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes` which isn't working.

I get this error when I run `cgconfigparser`:

```
root@server:~# cgconfigparser -l /etc/cgconfig.conf
Error: failed to set /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/group1/memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes: Invalid argument
cgconfigparser; error loading /etc/cgconfig.conf: Failed to remove a non-empty group
root@server:~#
```

Here is the group:

```
group group1 {
  memory {
    memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes = 512m;
  }
}
```

Any idea on what's wrong?

EDIT: I've enabled cgroups memory and swapaccount in the GRUB command already but still the issue occurs.

Comment: Could you post the additions to the kernel commandline you added to GRUB, and also the output of `cat /proc/cmdline` please? Apart from that, try as mentioned in this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125024/83329

Comment: @doktor5000 - `root@server:~# cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 root=/dev/sda2 ro rd.driver=raid1,ahci,dm_mod,part_gpt domdadm dolvm rd.lvm.vg=vg00 rd.lvm.lv=vg00/usr console=ttyS0,57600 console=tty0 net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0 quiet cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1`

Comment: Just to be clear: you say you're trying to limit a user using cgroup v2, but this is legacy cgroup v1, which has a significant number of deficiencies :-)

Comment: @ChrisDown - The system supports cgroup v2 but idk why it uses v1

Comment: It's not the system, you're explicitly using cgroupv1 with that stanza. For cgroupv2, have a look at e.g. https://facebookmicrosites.github.io/cgroup2/docs/memory-controller.html you would probably want `memory.max` and `memory.swap.max`
@ChrisDown good catch ;)

Comment: @doktor5000 Heh, linked to my own documentation ;-) If your system is forcing v1 controllers, you might want to use `cgroup_no_v1=all` on the kernel command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @doktor5000 for providing the answer [Limit memory usage for a single Linux process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44985/limit-memory-usage-for-a-single-linux-process/125024#125024)

I concluded the following from that answer: `memory.limit_in_bytes` must be set before `memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes`, and `memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes` must be bigger than or equal to `memory.limit_in_bytes`

So in my case, this group configuration worked:

```
group group1 {
  memory {
    memory.limit_in_bytes = 512m;
    memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes = 512m;
  }
}
```

which seens to limit the memory+swap of the user to 512MB. I've tested it with https://github.com/julman99/eatmemory